# How to save the debugging info to a file?

Tags: python, pdb

I'm using PDB to debug python code, I wonder is there a way to save all the info appeared on the terminal during the whole debugging process to a file? copy-paste is not realistic here.

Help me edit the tags or move this question to a more appropriate place if this question is not proper on `stackoverflow`.

I guess I need to write a script to track the info on the terminal form the beginning to the end of the debugging process.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `script` command is the most convenient way of doing this in unix based OSes, it lets you save everything that appeared in your terminal to a file. You stop recording with `exit` or `C-d` so it can go as long as you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can record your entire terminal session using [asciinema](https://asciinema.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you just try:

```
python test.py > outlog.txt
```

when run in the terminal. Output will be written in to the file.

You can use [tee](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/tee.1.html) if you want to capture terminal session:

```
bash | tee log.txt
```

now do whatever you want in the terminal. All output will be written in to the file. Do your debug process in the same terminal. You can read the file after closing the terminal.

eg:

my commands :

```
bash | tee log.txt
ls
echo hi
python
print hi
exit()
```

output of the file after closing the terminal:

```
log.txt
hi
hi
```

Comment: I need to see the whole debug process.

Comment: `history > outlog.txt` only export the bash command I used before in a `txt` file. that's no what I need.